# Append to System PATH variable without including the User's PATH variable

Tags: windows-8, command-line, environment-variables, path

Imagine the following environment variables:

**System** PATH = `C:\Windows`
Bob's **User** PATH = `C:\Users\Bob`

In a command prompt the `PATH` command returns `C:\Windows;C:\Users\Bob`

After running `setx /m PATH "C:\Node;%PATH%"`
**System** PATH = `C:\Node;C:\Windows;C:\Users\Bob`

In a new command prompt the `PATH` command returns `C:\Node;C:\Windows;C:\Users\Bob;C:\Users\Bob`

Another user, Alice, logs in.
Alice's **User** PATH = `C:\Users\Alice`

On a command prompt the `PATH` command returns `C:\Node;C:\Windows;C:\Users\Bob;C:\Users\Alice`

Bob has a duplicate path in his `PATH` variable, and Alice has Bob's paths in her `PATH` variable.

Is there a way to append to the System `PATH` without polluting it with the current user's `PATH`?

Comment: In Windows 7, you can look up the **System** Path with `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v path`. If that still works on Windows 8, then use that to build the new value. (You'll have to figure out how to parse the output of `reg query`.)

Comment: @Scott I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you post it as one and include a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7, you can look up the System Path with

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v path
```

If that still works on Windows 8, then use that to build the new value.

You'll have to figure out how to parse the output of `reg query`. 
Here's something that might work:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\…\Environment" /v path') do set currentValue=%c
```

where

- the `'reg query "HKLM\…\Environment" /v path'` string
  is the `reg query` command (given above) enclosed in single quotes.
- `a`, `currentValue`, and `c` are variable names. 
  You can choose whatever variable names you want,
  with the constraints that the `a` and the `c` must be single letters, two letters apart
  (e.g., you could use `n` and `p`, or `x` and `z`).
- `for /f "options" %variable in ('command1') do command2`
  runs `command1`, parses the output, assigns value(s) to the `%variable`(s) (`%a`, above; but see also below) and executes `command2`.
- `tokens=1,2*` means that `%a` gets the first token (word) of each (remaining) line,
  `%b` gets the second word, and `%c` gets the rest of the line.

  - The first word is `path` (the value name).
  - The second word is `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (the value type).
  - The rest of the line is the value.

  (You could just use `tokens=2*` and then `currentValue=%b`.)

So, after executing the above, you should be able to do

```
setx PATH "C:\Node;%currentValue%" /m
```

- If you do this in a script (a `.BAT` file), use `%%a` and `%%c`.
- Be sure to test this with `echo` commands before you do it with `setx`.

Comment: The only issue I'm running into now is that SETX is truncating my variable to 1024 characters. Looks like Powershell is going to be a better way to go.

Comment: This is also working on Windows 8.

Comment: An external command will have a command-line length limit. Such commands ought to have a way to take parameters from a fike instead.

Comment: @jdlugosz: Ironically, `setx` _does_ have a `/f` option that tells it to read from a file. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to tell it that spaces are not delimiters, so you can't handle commonplace `PATH` values like `Program Files`.

Comment: Try quotes like on the command line?  Well, [it's been discussed before](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+setx+spaces&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) time and time again.

Comment: Example from the docs page: `setx MACHINE "Brand1 Computer" /m` does that not workmwith a file? How typical.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put Bob's specific path in the System Path value that's used by everyone.

Read the old value of the system path, modify that, and set the new value. If `cmd.exe` (apparently the `set` command can create/modify/delete but not read) doesn't provide those features, put it in a program called by the batch file.

The system path value is found (and changed) via the Registry.  I just search for the value I know it has to discover exactly where,  the Google that key path to check what's been said about it.
(later: they are `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and `HKCU\Environment`)

Any more-advanced scripting language for Windows, or with Windows API support, can handle that. Or, a compiled program executable in your language of choice.

he CMD replacement shell [Take Command](https://jpsoft.com/) has a @REGQUERY function:

```
echo %@REGQUERY["HKLM_64\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path"]
```

since it sounds like you have a specific machine in mind, you can install [TCC/LE (free)](https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html) and use that to interpret your batch file.

Comment: "Don't put Bob's specific path in the System Path value that's used by everyone." Duh. The OP is asking *how* to do that, and your "answer" does not answer that question. Telling the user to Google his problem is not an acceptable answer. ... ... ... ... ... ... P.S. Windows doesn't have a program called `command.exe` any more.

Comment: I didn't say Google the *problem*:  I said in general one can find the needed Registry setting by searching the registry for the value you know it has, and then *be sure to* double-check to make sure people have not posted things like "don't do that!" or, having been armed with the correct exact name, will turn up correct syntax and usage for that particular setting.

Comment: @jdlugosz I'm finding it hard to understand a lot of what you're trying to say in your answer. Do you have a working example that doesn't require a third-party app? Powershell might be an option though. This is not for a specific computer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell, but that, vbscript, jscript, and any real language for Windows should have a way to read the Registry.  Find the funcgion for reading a Registry string value, and use that with the argument illustrated.